# Wacom Intuous doesn't get recognized in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb, wacom

Wacom Intuos Pro PTH-651

Hardware is ok because it works on Windows.

Running `lsusb` returns:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1005:b155 Apacer Technology, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 056a:0315 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But running `xinput list` returns no Wacom device. `xsetwacom --list devices` also, nothing. What could be the problem? I installed latest versions of libwacom2 (0.22-1), libwacom-common (0.22-1) and xserver-xorg-input-wacom (1:0.32.0).

Running `sudo evtest` returns:

```
/dev/input/event0:  Sleep Button
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  ITE8708 CIR transceiver
/dev/input/event3:  MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (ite-cir)
/dev/input/event4:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event5:  HDA Intel PCH Mic
/dev/input/event6:  HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/dev/input/event7:  HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event8:  HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event9:  Logitech USB Receiver
/dev/input/event10: Logitech USB Receiver
/dev/input/event11: Logitech USB Receiver
/dev/input/event12: Logitech USB Receiver
/dev/input/event13: gpio-keys
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` has no mention of Wacom when I plug it in.

Only `dmesg -w` detects it:

```
[2017799.823996] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[2017800.050551] [usb.001.032] /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 added.
```

`lsusb -v | grep Wacom`
returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 032: ID 056a:0315 Wacom Co., Ltd 
  idVendor           0x056a Wacom Co., Ltd
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: A few questions. Are you running Wayland? What is your kernel version? Have you tried installing input-wacom (the up to date kernel driver)? Also does "sudo evtest" list the device (like xinput list but for the kernel)?

Comment: @AaronSkomra Thanks for your reply! I have x server, Type=x11. Kernel version is 4.2.8. I updated the main post with Evtest, and I'm trying to figure out how to install input-wacom :) Maybe it's useful that Ubuntu is running on Qnap hardware, TS-253A

Comment: input-wacom kernel driver is xserver-xorg-input-wacom, right? That is on its newest version (1:0.32.0).

Comment: When I run tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log nothing comes up when I plug in the Wacom. When I plug in other usb devices, I see the lines come in. Only dmesg detects it.

Comment: The input-wacom kernel driver is not xserver-xorg-input-wacom, but this is may not directly a kernel driver problem. My guess is that this a virtualization problem. Is the QNAP is a virtualization device?

Comment: @AaronSkomra It is a LXC container. I would think so too, but all the other peripherals work, like wireless mouse and keyboard, and a webcam.

Comment: Hi @Janjko. For the first step try installing input-wacom. https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source

Comment: If that fails to work, please try running this script: https://github.com/linuxwacom/wacom-hid-descriptors/blob/master/scripts/sysinfo.sh and posting the output to a pastebin or similar.

Comment: @AaronSkomra Installing input-wacom didn't work. I'm afraid the problem is [you can't install linux kernel modules in an LXC guest machine.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314817/how-do-i-install-a-kernel-module-in-an-lxc-guest-machine). After running the script i got lot's of files, one of them [kernel-drivers.txt](https://pastebin.com/5K2ReZPL). I'm looking into QNAP forums about installing new hardware. Thanks for your help! I guess this is getting out of the scope of this question.